# Passing props from react-cosmos to styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have the following component where I have applied the css using styled-components:

import styled from 'styled-components'

```
// square-block css can be re-written as a styled-component(???)
const SquareBlock = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
`

export default SquareBlock
```

I would like to use the following fixture with react-cosmos to adapt the `background-color` of the component based on the props:

```
import { COLORS } from '../../../constants/tetronimo'

export default {
  color: COLORS.I
}
```

In the React developer tools I noticed that the component `PropsProxy` had a fixture prop which has the `color` property:

```
JSON.stringify($r.props.fixture, null, 2)

{
  "color": "#3cc7d6"
}
```

How can I ensure that props are passed correctly to `react-cosmos`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props need to be placed under `fixture.props` in the latest version of React Cosmos, but you seem to have already [figured](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/flatris-copy/blob/master/src/components/__fixtures__/SquareBlock/color-of-l-tetronimo.js) this out. Does this solve your problem?